# Why does an improper integral turn into an answer with factorial?

Tags: improper-integrals, exponential-function

Suppose I have

$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{2n+1}e^{-y}dy$

Why does this integral equal

$(2n+1)!$   ?

Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Because, $\int_0^{\infty} y^{k}e^{-y}\,dy=k\int_0^{\infty}y^{k-1}e^{-y}\,dy$ by integration by parts.

Comment: Try doing successive integration by parts. Tabular method is your friend here.

Comment: See the article on the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeated integration by parts.

$\int_0^\infty y^{2n+1}e^{-y}dy = -y^{2n+1}e^{-y}|_0^\infty + (2n+1)\int_0^\infty y^{2n}e^{-y}dy = (2n+1)\int_0^\infty y^{2n}e^{-y}dy$.